# for, do, done applying in convert txt to biom format in linux

Tags: linux, for-loop, biom

I have a folder with a numbers of `txt` files, I would like to apply the `for do do` loop to convert them from `txt` to `biom` files, the following is what I did:

```
for txt in folder/*.txt
do biom convert -i $txt -o *.biom --to-hdf5
done
```

but I got a combined biom file.

How can I revise my above code, changing the multiple txt files to biom files, without changing the original file name?

like: `test.txt` to `test.biom`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick (assuming there are now spaces in the filenames):

```
for txt in folder/*.txt
do biom convert -i $txt -o  ${txt%.txt}.biom --to-hdf5
done
```

The bash substitution `${txt%.txt}` strips `.txt` of the variable, and we tack `.biom` at the end.